# Install Jboss application server on win vista

Tags: java, jboss

I want to install Jboss app server 4.2.2. I've downloaded .zip installation from their website and here is what I get when I extract the zip file like in the picture below :

[image]

I've used their tutorial guide to try to install it but I can't get it working .. http://www.jboss.org/file-access/default/members/jbossas/freezone/docs/Installation_Guide/4/pdf/Installation_Guide.pdf

How do I install it ?? where is the installation located in these files ?
tnx

Comment: BTW why 4.2.2? 5.1 is out there!

Comment: I dunno company policy..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The startup script is `bin/run.bat`

JBoss doesn't need installing, just unpacking and running.